# Error getting values from BufferedReader (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, bufferedreader

I have to get json from an URL, and I'm running the methods in a AsyncTask.
When the JSON is to long, it gives me an error in the task.

I'm running the debugger and the problem is in this line:

```
JSONArray resultsArray = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()).nextValue();
```

This only occurs when the json is too long, but the debugger only show me an error in the task:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer

Anyone knows why?

Comment: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer

Comment: How big is too big?  KBs?  10s of KBs?  10s of MBs?

Comment: Right now the json file have about 10 MB, but it is not static, so it can be bigger in the future...